# Sony Nex-5N:Unable to Display pictures

Tags: troubleshooting, error, sony-nex

Just got my Nex-5n with 18-55 kit lens yesterday. I have tried shooting with it in various settings. Most of the pictures can be display for 1 or 2 sec after shooting but after that, it is impossible to view them using the camera. The camera displays "Unable to Display". Anybody knows why?

Comment: It's unable to display pictures you just shot? Can you copy them off of the memory card to a computer, and do they seem fine in that case? Have you tried reformatting the memory card in the camera?

Comment: actually I've just fixed it. It's the faulty SDHC card I used caused the problem. I buy a new card and everything's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty SDHC card caused the problem. Bought a new one and work like charm.